# I can't get outlook to make new mail sounds

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have tried the 'sounds' option in control panel like [this article](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/Change_the_New_Mail_Sound_in_Outlook_Windows_Live_Mail.htm) says and I applied a new sound and everything yet still no email notification sound will play

Comment: Other sounds work on your computer, correct?

Comment: indeed, I can hear anything else working just fine

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: 2010 is the version i have on win 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably in Outlook actually. Try this:

1. Click **File**>**Options**.
2. Click **Mail**.
3. Make sure **Play a sound**, under **Message arrival**, is checked.

Comment: Can't freaking believe I missed that. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey, we all do things like that. No worries.